# Swift Argument type 'XXX' expected to be an instance of a class or class-constrained type

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm a very beginner of Swift & SwiftUI. I'm trying to set ID to View in ScrollView, so then I can use ScrollViewReader to scroll to top position(first item).What I'm struggling is when I try to get the index of an array, I get the error **Argument type 'XXX' expected to be an instance of a class or class-constrained type**. How can I solve this issue? thx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fc6A.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct PokedexListView: View {
    let pokemons: [Pokemon]
    let hasMoreData: Bool
    
    var fetchListener: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach (pokemons) { pokemon in
                            PokemonCellView(pokemon: pokemon)
                                .id(self.getID(pokemon: pokemon))
                        }
                        if hasMoreData {
                            LoadingFooterView()
                                .onAppear { fetchListener() }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .overlay(
                    ScrollTopBtnView(toTop: { scrollView.scrollTo(0) })
                        .padding(.trailing)
                        .padding(.bottom, 80),
                    alignment: .bottomTrailing
                )
                .navigationTitle("Pokedex")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getID(pokemon: Pokemon) -> Int {
        return pokemons.firstIndex { p in p === pokemon  } ?? -1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace `===` with `==`

```
return pokemens.firstIndex { p in p.id == pokemon.id  } ?? -1
```

`===` is used to compare objects not primitive/struct data types , or make `pokemon` type a `class` not `struct`

Comment: Hi @Sh_Khan thx for your answer.
I found that when I change to the code below then everything goes fine, so just curious about in Swift, can't I compare two objects ? 
`return pokemons.firstIndex { p in p.id == pokemon.id  } ?? -1`

Comment: == would also be used to compare objects/instances for equality as in A is same as B. You might sometimes need to compare objects to see if they are not just equal/equivalent, but are indeed the _exact same object_ as in "A is different instance to B although they're the same", then you use the pointer equality ===

Comment: Still not really understand why I couldn't compare two objects. Or in swift struct data is not an object ? Cuz when I use the code below it shows this error **Referencing operator function '==' on 'Equatable' requires that 'Pokemon' conform to 'Equatable'** .
`return pokemons.firstIndex { $0 == pokemon  } ?? -1`

Comment: @Jung struct is a value type not a reference type like a class